# weightsum text and image are not displaying properly in xml android

Tags: android, android-layout-weight

For the below xml code weight sum is 4 i have divided into 4 parts .2 parts for displaying text and remaining 2 parts again divided into 2 parts . 1 part contains text and another part contains image .but for the send 2 parts are not displaying properly.

text of the second layout is moving left side .
Can any one help me

```
<LinearLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:orientation="horizontal"
                            android:weightSum="4"
                            android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:id="@+id/outcomess"
                            android:layout_below="@+id/statuss">

                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/text_outcome"
                                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_below="@+id/bill_district"
                                android:paddingLeft="16dp"
                                android:paddingRight="16dp"
                                android:text="Outcome"
                                android:textStyle="bold"
                                android:layout_weight="2"
                                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                                android:textSize="15sp"
                                />


                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal"
                        android:weightSum="2">
                            <TextView
                                android:id="@+id/outcome"
                                style="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
                                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                android:text="Not Interested"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:textColor="@color/gray"
                                android:textSize="15sp"/>
                            <ImageView
                                android:layout_width="20dp"
                                android:layout_height="20dp"
                                android:id="@+id/image"
                                android:layout_weight="1"
                                android:src="@drawable/ic_thumb_up_black_24dp">

                            </ImageView>
                    </LinearLayout>


                        </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Upload images of what is result of this and what you want to achieve

Comment: which type of layout actually you want ?? Share a screenshot or image of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>  you mentioned weightSum="4" so add weight second Linearlayout


  <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/outcomess"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/statuss"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp"
        android:weightSum="4">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_outcome"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/bill_district"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingRight="16dp"
            android:text="Outcome"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="2"
            android:weightSum="">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/outcome"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:text="Not Interested"
                android:textSize="15sp" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:src="@drawable/car">

            </ImageView>
        </LinearLayout>


    </LinearLayout>
```